# Can derived class choose how much properties from the base class to implement?

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, interface

I have one class that has let's say 3 properties in it. I want this class to be derived by an interface and whenever the interface is inherited I want to be able to leave some properties unused and I don't want them to appear in the IntelliSense. Every class derived from the interface can have different amount of properties implemented. I also have a normal class which directly inherits from the base class and implements all 3 properties.

Is it possible to do this ?

Here's my illustration of how I imagine it, hope it will become clearer to you.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you're looking for?

```
public class BaseClass : ISomeInterface, ISomeOther
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public int Prop2 { get; set; }
    public int Prop3 { get; set; }
}

public class Derived : BaseClass
{
    // inherits all 3 props
}

public interface ISomeInterface
{
    int Prop1 { get; }
    int Prop2 { get; }
}

public interface ISomeOther
{
    int Prop3 { get; }
}

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        BaseClass instance1 = new BaseClass();      // IntelliSense shows all 3 props
        Derived instance2 = new Derived();          // IntelliSense shows all 3 props
        ISomeInterface instance3 = new BaseClass(); // IntelliSense shows 2 props from interface
        ISomeOther instance4 = new BaseClass();     // IntelliSense shows only Prop3
    }
}
```

By decomposing the functionality in certain interfaces, you can offer a certain subset of functionality according to which interface being used.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however this is quite not practical in my case because I have more than 3 properties and if I want to create a class that has prop 1 let's say I will need to create new interface for that purpose and with even more properties I will end up with tons of interfaces.

Comment: Of course you shouldn't expose a single interface of each property. Maybe they can be grouped in a meaningful way.

Comment: They really cant be grouped because my properties are for a game and those properties represent different character statuses like attack,defense,evasion etc. a unit can have all different varieties of statuses.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot derive an interface from a class, but you can *implement a class from an interface*.

So, start with the interface with the smaller set of properties, then implement it in subclasses and add the additional properties to that.